# criar uma função global no vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Boa tarde,
Sou iniciante tanto em javascript quanto em vue, e estou tendo algumas dificuldades em criar uma função global no vue. Alguém poderia me passar um exemplo? Grata

Comment: Ola Elisangela, seja bem vinda ao Stackoverflow em Português. Pode nos mostrar em qual parte do seu código esta tendo dificuldades? Faça um [tour também](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Oi Elisangela. Pode explicar melhor o que você quer dizer com função global? E pode dar mais detalhes sobre como está estruturando seu código? Por exemplo, usa algum gerenciador de módulos? Seu código tem `require` ou `import`?

Comment: bom dia, tenho uma requisição ajax sendo executada no gancho mounted, porém essa mesma requisição preciso fazer ao selecionar um item do select (estou usando o materialize para os componentes), pois ele é passado como parametro na minha consulta. Porém não estou conseguindo chamar essa mesma função criada no gancho mounted no evento do select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para adicionar um método global ao Vue você pode criar um plugin:

**De acordo com [Vue.js - Plugins](https://vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html)**:

```
MeuPlugin.install = function (Vue, options) {
  // 1. Adiciona o método global ou propriedade
  Vue.meuMetodoGlobal = ...
  // 2. Adiciona uma diretiva global
  Vue.directive('minha-diretiva', {})
  // 3. Adiciona um método de instância
  Vue.prototype.$meuMetodo = ...
}
```

Depois você adiciona o plugin ao Vue:

```
Vue.use(MeuPlugin)
```

No seu código, para chamar o método.

```
Vue.meuMetodoGlobal(parametros);
```

**Referência:** [Include global functions in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373047/include-global-functions-in-vue-js)

Comment: bom dia, estou com dúvida em onde criar o plugin. Como estou utilizando o vue router, deveria criar um novo arquivo .vue para meu plugin e importá-lo no main? obrigada

Comment: Para melhor organização sim